# Determining time it would take to exhaust IVs on 802.11b/g/n

Tags: network, wep, initialisation-vector

I'm trying to learn about WEP attacks at the moment. I know that attacks against WEP require collisions of the initialization vectors. Is there a way to determine how long it would take for the vectors to be exhausted on 802.11b/g/n networks before an IV repeats? Let's say the data portion of the frame is 1500 bytes and the max bandwidth is being fully used by the frames.

Trying to figure out an equation. Working with 802.11b here. So the max bandwidth is 11Mbps. 1500 byte packet. IV's are 24 bit. So doing some conversion, here's a formula I came up with but I feel like I'm missing a number which I labeled as 'x'.

```
1500 * (x / (11 * 10^6)) * 2^24 = time in seconds
```

Wait..24 bit is 3 bytes so, x would equal 8?

so the equation is now

```
1500 * (8 / (11 * 10^6)) * 2^24 = 18000 seconds
```

Does this seem correct?

Comment: This can give you some insight http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41702/how-do-poor-quality-initialization-vectors-affect-the-security-of-cbc-mode?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. Still having some issues figuring it out. It looks like there's an equation to be formed to figure it out, I'm just having trouble with that.

Comment: Your numbers are a bit off.  11 megabit 802.11b doesn't have a max bandwidth of 11 megabit, that's the raw rate.  Realistically it's more like half that.

Comment: Yeah but just given that the full bandwidth supported is actually being used, it would be 11 right?

Comment: no, as Steve said, it would be a bit less than half that. The maximum bandwidth usable for traffic is a lot less than the raw bandwidth.